# Qual è il significato di "dare il filo" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto questo dialogo tra Milton (un giovane partigiano) e una vecchia signora:

> – Che fate? Io non ho piú bisogno di niente.
>   
>       – Aspetta a dirlo. Ho una cosa che ti potrebbe interessare. Voleva uscire a dirtela mio genero ma io l’ho
>   convinto a restarsene al chiuso e lasciar fare a me.
>   
>       – Che cosa?
>       – Una cosa che da tempo volevamo dire al piú vecchio dei miei nipoti che sono nella Stella Rossa. Ma ora
>   avremmo deciso di dirla a te che ne hai bisogno urgente
>   e non puoi aspettare di piú.
>   
>       – Ma che cos’è?
>   
>       – È che io posso **darti il filo** per il fascista che cerchi. 
>       Milton posò il sandwich sull’orlo del contenitore. –
>   Intendiamoci. Io cerco un soldato, non un fascista borghese.
>       – E io ti segnalo un soldato. Un sergente.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "darti il filo" nel brano precedente. Si tratta di un modo di dire? L'ho cercata nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/F/filo.shtml), ma non l'ho trovata.

Più avanti nel libro, questa vecchia signora dice a Milton un'altra frase con questa stessa espressione:

> – Aspetta. E se ti andasse male? Se ti va male, dirai che siamo stati noi a **darti il filo**?

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "dare il filo" in questo contesto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non ho sentito l'espressione prima d'ora, ma dal contesto direi che si tratta di "metterti sulla giusta pista/strada", "darti una dritta per quel che cerchi". In altre parole vogliono indicare a Milton l'identità di un militare fascista (probabilmente per catturarlo / fargli un'imboscata).

Answer (score 1):

Forse è un po' azzardata. Ma se derivasse dal **filo di Arianna** ?

Quindi guidare, condurre, segnare la strada per, indicare ..